# Access to the path [C:\blah blah blah.txt] is denied

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008-r2

I have an C# app that simply reads an data from the server and translates them into a txt file. The codes were originally from VB 2005 or VB 2008 (inherited from my previous colleague who resigned) Thus, i imported all the codes into vb 2010. When i debug, the codes run perfectly fine. Whenever i publish as a exe file or a standalone, I encountered “Access to the path [C:\blah blah blah.txt] is denied". Nothing else is changed, I tried to change folder permissions and set it to owner and maximum rights to the user.

My server is Windows Server 2008 R2

> EDIT: im not using IIS as it is not a web server, its just a normal server holding my database.
>
> EDIT 2: i can only get it to run without the error if i "Run as administrator" whereas my user has no admin rights

Comment: Please check the permission of executable files in your directory.

Comment: Hi sir, the permissions are set to maximum rights to the user, even changed the ownership.

Comment: There is no problem and you already have the answer.

Comment: The user that runs the application must have access rights to the file you are trying to read.

Comment: Hi leppie and Trikks, but the user has no admin rights to start off with. And its not possible to assign her admin rights. Is there any other ways?

Comment: Dear friends, whoever flagged it down, please let me know my mistake rather than flagging it down bluntly. We are all here to learn. :)

Comment: Prolly i got my solution, i added the user as local admin. And the program worked.
I checked with my server guys, they informed me that access to the server required admin rights. 
Thanks everyone for helping. Much appreciated! :)

Comment: You should _not_ have to add a user as a local admin just to give them access to a folder - just modify the permissions on the folder to allow non-admin users to edit contents!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason being is probably because for one your application is a Click Once application which will require elevation as it runs under the users context, therefore if you do not have the rights to access C:\blah blah and make changes you will also be unable to use your application.

My Recommendation to you?

I personally would write the Text File into the Users Documents folder or anything associated with the Users Profile, that way your click once application should never need to be elevated as it right now runs in a managed environment with some serious restrictions.

Hope this clears things up a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

Go to properties of your exe file and checked the "Run as Administrator" check.

Comment: Yes sir, it is set as "Run as Administrator"

Answer (score 0):

Don't write into the root of the system drive... that's the issue here (newer OS have permissions set to prevent arbitrary applications from polluting the system root).

Comment: Hi Lucero, yes i understand that. Thus, i changed the root to C:\[the folder i want the data to be exported into]

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the folder which contains your files, choose "Properies". Go to the security tab. Click "Edit Permissions"... Click "Add". When prompted for a username, enter `Everyone`. Set permissions as required (at least read, possible create/change).

Now try running the executable as a non-administrator

Instead of `Everyone` you can use the username of the specific user you want to be able to use the app or of any windows saecurity group they are in.

Comment: Hi @Basic, i tried that, it threw me back with the same original error. Its okay. My server folks told me, they must be administrators to access to the server database. thank you :)